# Can't create pdfs with pdfkit - PDFKit::NoExecutableError

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I got pdfkit install and even set up wkhtmltopdf installed as well however I'm getting the following error everytime I try to create a pdf.

```
PDFKit::NoExecutableError 
No wkhtmltopdf executable found at bundler: command not found: which
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
>> Please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/wiki/Installing-WKHTMLTOPDF
```

My Gemfile has the following:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem "wkhtmltopdf"
gem 'pdfkit'
```

And my application.rb has the following entry:

```
config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware", :print_media_type => true
```

am I missing something here - I've run a bundle install but still get this error everytime I try to create a pdf. Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read Install readme here:

> https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit

so you need to install wkhtmltopdf manualy:

> https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/wiki/Installing-WKHTMLTOPDF

or like this

```
gem install wkhtmltopdf-binary
```

**PS**

check `which wkhtmltopdf`

and create new file config/initializers/pdfkit.rb

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = 'PATH/TO/wkhtmltopdf'
end
```

Comment: windows? lol :) Download wkht.. from http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list and install it. then put your installation path into pdfkit.rb

Comment: Setting `config.wkhtmltopdf to '/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf'` worked for me when using AWS elastic beanstalk with `gem install wkhtmltopdf`.  Means I didn't have to set up container commands to install wkhtmltopdf on my ec2 instances ... thanks

Comment: check that last comment ... I meant `gem install wkhtmltopdf-binary`

Answer (score 2):

Ali,

I don't see you mention which operating system you're on.  Fl00r, and I, are both assuming that it's a Linux system, so adjust accordingly.  This is what I needed to do to make PDFKit work with wkhtmltopdf for my Rails application running on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Remove any reference to `wkhtmltopdf` or `wkhtmltopdf-binary` from your `Gemfile`.

Add only `gem 'pdfkit', :require => 'pdfkit'` to your Gemfile

In your `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` file add

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

Remove any `config/initializers/pdfkit.rb` file

Uninstall the gems from the server that you're running the Rails application on

```
gem uninstall wkhtmltopdf -a
gem uninstall wkhtmltopdf-binary -a
```

Download to your server `wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0_rc2-static-amd64.tar.bz2` from [the project download site here](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount).  There is a bug in the latest suggested download versions that prevent a user from being able to select and copy text from a generated PDF, but this version doesn't have that bug.  This issue is referenced at http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=886

Extract the executable from the tar archive

```
tar -xvf wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0_rc2-static-amd64.tar.bz2
```

Move it to the `/usr/local/bin/` directory

```
sudo mv wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0.rc2 /usr/local/bin/
```

Now setup a symbolic link to the file so it's easy to upgrade at a later point

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0.rc2 /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Set the permissions on the file

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0.rc2
```

After doing all of this, and restarting my server, PDFKit will now use the wkhtmltopdf that I have installed on the server.

Caveat: On one occasion my Rails application started reporting that it couldn't find the wkhtmltopdf executable in the path, not sure why as nothing changed.  Restarting the server corrected this issue.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. I tried the solution posted in here https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/issues/123