# Error with Ruby and PDFKit on Appfog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, appfog, pdfkit

I'm trying to use [PDFkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) with Ruby on Rails on Appfog.

I am using the gem **wkhtmltopdf-binary** and have also tried changing the **PDFKit config.wkhtmltopdf  path**, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9598362/486849) on a related question suggests.

I always get this error:

```
PDFKit::NoExecutableError (No wkhtmltopdf executable found at ...
```

Also, whatever path I specify in the PDFKit config.wkhtmltopdf follows the *at* in the error message.

I'm a begginer at Ruby and RoR. All I did was put the example code given in the PDFKit docs in a *welcome* controller on the app and then ran it on the browser. Then I received the error in the browser *We're sorry, but something went wrong.* and finally I checked the logs of my application on Appfog.

What I need help with, and what I think complicates this, is the fact that the application is on Appfog. I can't install the binary of *wkhtmltopdf* and so I have no idea of how to do this.

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: where is your binary location? I would suggest `vendor/pdfkit/` I had the same issue with using `pdftk` on Heroku and this is how i solved it.

Comment: @engineersmnky I don't understand, did you install wkhtmltopdf? How? or how else did you got it working?